# How are C/S RTE ports implemented in AUTOSAR?

Tags: autosar

I'm wondering about this because they are vastly different than S/R RTE ports. Data which is sent through the S/R can be observed/recorded. After all RTE is the one who takes the incoming data and copies it to a temporary/direct location. That data is quantifiable. BUT, when talking about C/S, client somehow has access to a functions which are offered by a server. Those functions are executed in clients context, not the server context. Does anybody know how this is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what your question is, because somehow you already answered yourself by writing "when talking about C/S, client somehow has access to a functions which are offered by a server. Those functions are executed in clients context, not the server context.".
So, best case, the client simply invokes a function in the server.
When speaking about Client and Server in different Tasks or even on different uC cores, then events will also be involved and the call is getting more complex.

Comment: But those functions which are offered by a server, are only classified as server functions when looking at the architecture, but when everything is compiled those function calls are part of the client SWC. So there is no "real" client-server communication. It's not like you're sending an event that will trigger a function call in servers context.